# How to merge the perspective image(3D Transform)?

Tags: iphone, uiimage, core-image, cgimage

[image]

How to merge these two images(see attached image).I am using the below code. Its working for ordinary images not for 3D transform images. How to handle this issue. I have searched lot of times still not getting the proper result. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

```
UIImage *mergedImage;
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(backgroundImageView.frame.size);
[backgroundImageView.layer  renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()]; //bacgroundImageView here
mergedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: I see that you're using my GPUImage framework here at some point (those are the sample images I ship with the framework). Why not use a blend filter from that, combined with a transform filter, instead of working with UIViews?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a `CGImageRef` that contain the distorted image to put on top, (with the background of that image being 0% alpha) that way you could blend the images using your above code.

So what you are truly looking for is how to apply a 3D transform to an image. More precisely, as you are looking for "perspective" in you own words, you are looking on how to warp an homography to an image.

The [CoreImage programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/CoreImage.pdf) specify that `CIPerspectiveTransform` is the way to go, unfortunately for you this is not available on iOS as of iOS 5.1.

So you are left with a few choices :

- If you want to display only the result blend and not manipulate it, you can use two `UIImageView`s on top of each other, the one containing the perspective image being transformed using a cleverly designed `CATransform3D`
- If you absolutely need to blend the images, you will need to use another framework such as [OpenCV](http://opencv.itseez.com) (`warpPerspective()`is the function you are looking for) or OpenGL ES

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `renderInContext:` only flattens 2D transforms. It cannot flatten 3D transforms applied to layers. There is no way around this.

Comment: Thanks sudo rm -rf...Any other idea... I want to merge the images..How to do?