# How to merge the 3d transformed image?

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to merge the perspective image(3D Transform)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12457047/how-to-merge-the-perspective-image3d-transform)

How to merge the 3D transformed image with the background image? I am using the below code.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(backgroundImageView.frame.size);
[backgroundImageView.layer  renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()]; //bacgroundImageView here
overlappedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Its working fine, but I change the 3D transform to that image(cat image[image]) Its not working. Please see the attached image. 1st image is transformed image, 2nd image is merged image(this is the issue).Please help me. I have wasted more time for this issue. I hope any one help me. Thanks in advance.