# How can I merge two images after change the 3D transform?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to merge the perspective image(3D Transform)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12457047/how-to-merge-the-perspective-image3d-transform)

How can I merge two images after change the 3D Transform? I am using two images

(i) Background image is normal image.

(ii) Foreground image change the 3D transform.

Now I merge the two images. But not merged the images, I am using the below code. This code working fine for without 3D transform.

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(backgroundImageView.frame.size);
CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[imageView.layer renderInContext:ctx];
UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(newImage, nil, nil, nil);
return newImage;
```

I searched lot, But 3D Transformed image not supported the layer.

How to I got this feature. I really must this feature on my app. Any idea, source code, suggestion, advice, always welcome. Please help me. [image]

Comment: Please don't ask the same question twice.  If you didn't like the answer the first time you asked, you can un-accept the answer you accepted on that question.  If you need more help, you can offer a bounty on your original question.

Comment: Also, look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10677684/77567).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
- (UIImage*)mergeImage:(UIImage*)first withImage:(UIImage*)second
{
 // get size of the first image
 CGImageRef firstImageRef = first.CGImage;
 CGFloat firstWidth = CGImageGetWidth(firstImageRef);
 CGFloat firstHeight = CGImageGetHeight(firstImageRef);

 // get size of the second image
 CGImageRef secondImageRef = second.CGImage;
 CGFloat secondWidth = CGImageGetWidth(secondImageRef);
 CGFloat secondHeight = CGImageGetHeight(secondImageRef);

 // build merged size
 CGSize mergedSize = CGSizeMake(MAX(firstWidth, secondWidth), MAX(firstHeight, secondHeight));

 // capture image context ref
 UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(mergedSize);

 //Draw images onto the context
 [first drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, firstWidth, firstHeight)];
 [second drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, secondWidth, secondHeight)]; 

 // assign context to new UIImage
 UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

 // end context
 UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

 return newImage;
}
```

Comment: Thank you HDdeveloper...But this code only working for the 3D Transform. Please any other idea.